# How do I create summed values from a derived date column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Trying to create some code that will sum two revenue columns based on a derived date, where the derived date is a Saturday relative to date_1. The derived date part of the script is working (on a much larger data set than I've included below), however, the summation is going off of date_1 and not the derived date. I'm including an example of the data with a representative table and a few inserted rows along with the code that I currently have. (This is for SQL Server 2012.)

```
CREATE TABLE temp_1 (date_1 datetime, , rev_1 money, rev_2 money)

INSERT into temp1 VALUES (2015-12-22 00:00:00.000, 200, 300)
INSERT into temp1 VALUES (2015-12-23 00:00:00.000, 300, 400)
INSERT into temp1 VALUES (2015-12-24 00:00:00.000, 600, 700)
INSERT into temp1 VALUES (2015-12-28 00:00:00.000, 400, 500)
INSERT into temp1 VALUES (2015-12-29 00:00:00.000, 500, 600)
INSERT into temp1 VALUES (2015-12-30 00:00:00.000, 800, 900)
INSERT into temp1 VALUES (2015-12-31 00:00:00.000, 700, 800)

Select 
        DATEADD(DAY 
            ,  7 - (DATEPART(DW, CAST([date_1] as Date)))
            , CAST([date_1] as Date)) as 'Weekend Date',

        Round(Sum([rev_1]),2) as 'Rev1', 
        Round(SUM([rev_2]),2) as 'Rev2', 
        date_1 

    From temp_1

    Where [date_1] > '20151221' and [date_1] < '20160101'

Group by date_1
Order by 'Weekend Date'
```

My results are as per the preceding inserted values.

The desired results would be (note this excludes the column date_1):

```
Weekend Date   rev_1     rev_2
2015-12-26     1100      1400  
2016-01-02     2400      2800
```

Any assistance on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate by the expression you want, not just the column:

```
Select DATEADD(DAY,
               7 - (DATEPART(DW, CAST([date_1] as Date)))
               CAST([date_1] as Date)
              ) as WeekendDate,
       Round(Sum([rev_1]), 2) as Rev1, 
       Round(SUM([rev_2]), 2) as Rev2, 
       date_1 
From temp_1
Where [date_1] > '20151221' and [date_1] < '20160101'
Group by DATEADD(DAY,
               7 - (DATEPART(DW, CAST([date_1] as Date)))
               CAST([date_1] as Date)
              )
Order by WeekendDate ;
```

I strongly discourage you from using single quotes for column aliases.  Rules for naming:

- Avoid reserved words (which you do).
- Avoid spaces in names.
- Use square braces.

Comment: Thanks so much @ Gordon Linoff! This worked. For those who would look to this "DATEADD" portions of this there's a small syntactical correction. I'll show the full portion of the code here for clarity: DATEADD(DAY,
               7 - (DATEPART(DW, CAST([Transfer Date] as Date)))
               ,CAST([Transfer Date] as Date)
      )

Comment: As you have likely discerned, I'm new to SQL Server coding (I'm an IBM Cognos TM1 developer) that needed some quick help. @Gordon Linoff, at the end of your reply you strongly discouraged use of single quotes for column aliases. When I remove them, the code doesn't work. How should syntax work for aliasing columns? If this needs to be pushed to a different thread, please advice. Again, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the additional insight into alias naming conventions.